# Control picklist values visibility

Tags: picklist, relationships, childrelationship, parent, child-to-parent

I have a custom object called "A".

I have a custom object called "B".

Custom object "B" is related to custom object "A" via lookup field.

In custom object "A" as well as in custom object "B" I have a plicklist status field with values:
`Open`
`Active`
`Closed`

If "A" record status is set to `Open` I need it's child related "B" record status to allow only statuses `Open` and `Active` to be visible. Status `Closed` must be hidden in the "B" record.

If "A" record status is set to `Closed` I need it's child related "B" record status to allow only status `Closed` to be visible. Statuses `Open` and `Active`  must be hidden in the "B" record.

Please advise how it can be achieved.

Comment: You have do it by creating custom components , its standard it not available.  Refer this link - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lIypQAE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use record types to achieve this. On object ‘A’s’ open and active update the child record’s record type that has only open and active in the picklist values. Similarly when the status is Closed update the child record type that would have only Closed as an option. So you would need two different record types to accomplish this.